# I'm new to maven and jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

Please let me know how to run maven project using jenkins.

I have downloaded maven and jenkins. If I run mvn --version in shell prompt it shows details like :
Maven home, Java version, Java home, Default locale, OS name. Should I configure jenkins for using Maven. If so how should I configure..

In google I can find Maven Tutorials and Jenkins Tutorials. But I want to know how to use them together.

My source is in svn repository.

I have not started working with jenkins and maven yet.. Iam just a learner and trying to use it using some sample code.

Please provide me with some links to learn in detail about maven and Jenkins and also to run maven project using jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you start simple and build up in tiny pieces.

1. Create your own Maven project.  [Maven in 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) shows how to do this.  Make sure it builds locally via "mvn install"
2. Commit your new Maven project to SVN.
3. Create a Jenkins build.  Here's some [documentation](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/01/painless-maven-builds-with-jenkins.html) on setting up Jenkins for Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Add `pom.xml` to your project (project configuration) and build your project with command `mvn clean package`. When this is done, you can simply execute this command on jenkins.

Starting point:

- [Introduction to the POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)
- [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have once setup and run the maven project using Jenkins CI in one of my project. Please refer to this link :

[Selenium WebDriver + Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466700/selenium-webdriver-jenkins/24693115#24693115)